# I am having trouble returning a value (a function) [This question isnt a duplicate question]

Tags: javascript

Why does the inner function run when I write `return displayName;` but it doesn't run when I write `return displayName();`

I usually call a function like this:

```
functionName();
```

so I am very confused.

Here are my functions:

```js
function makeFunc() {
  var name = 'Mozilla';
  function displayName() {
    alert(name);
  }
  return displayName;
}

var myFunc = makeFunc();
myFunc();


VS

/*
function makeFunc() {
  var name = 'Mozilla';
  function displayName() {
    alert(name);
  }
  return displayName();
}

var myFunc = makeFunc();
myFunc();
*/
```

Comment: `displayName()` *calls* the function and returns nothing. You then probably get a type error when you try to *call that nothing* with `myFunc()` (where `myFunc` is nothing because that's what `makeFunc` returned).

Comment: I think both of your examples are the same, you might have missed the brackets.

Comment: Hi can you give us a bit more context of what you are trying to achieve, at the moment `alert('Mozilla');` gives the same result?

Comment: @PaddyHallihan Im not trying to achieve anything I am just testing what I am learning about.I am confused because the first code is the reason the alert works

Comment: @PaddyHallihan Why is it the reason the inner function is ran if youre supposed to call a function like this => nameOfFunction() ;

Comment: In many cases, instead of "function displayName() { ... }", you could also write "var displayName = function () { ... }". You could say that a function is a special kind of object. The function name acts as the binding name of that function object.

Comment: @BartHofland so the first code stores the displayName function in  the myFunc variable so the last statement is displayName() but it appears as myFunc() ? right?

Comment: @HeavensGate666 yes, you might look at it that way. And it is used heavily in JavaScript. By the way, your makeFunc() function is called a Higher-Order Function, since it is a function that returns a function. If you like a good read, I could suggest the free e-book "Eloquent JavaScript" from Marijn Haverbeke. It explains this stuff quite good. ;)

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
return displayName; // returns a function
```

You are returning a `function` which can, later on, be executed/called (as you are doing with the `myFunc` variable).

When you do:

```
return displayName(); // returns whatever the displayName function returns (undefined)
```

You are firstly calling the `displayName()` function, which in your case will evaluate to `undefined` as it does not `return` anything within it. So the above `return` statement is similar to:

```
return undefined;
```

Thus, as you are returning `undefined`, `myFunc` will be set equal to `undefined`, and so you cannot call it as a function (ie: `undefined()` will give you a TypeError)

So looking at your first example you can see it returns a function, which is later executed (read code comments for further explanation):

```js
function makeFunc() {
  var name = 'Mozilla';
  function displayName() {
    alert(name);
  }
  return displayName; // returns a function TO BE called LATER
}

var myFunc = makeFunc(); // makeFunc() "turns into" the returned (inner) function, so we have: var myFunc = displayName;
myFunc(); // call myFunc, like so myFunc(). As myFunc is equal to displayName, this is the same as doing displayName();
```

Comment: I am confused because the first code is the reason the alert works. Why is it the reason the inner function is ran if youre supposed to call a function like this => nameOfFunction()

Comment: @HeavensGate666 because `myFunc` holds the inner function, which allows you to call it using `myFunc()`. I've updated my answer (you can read the code comments for more details)

Comment: thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

When you type `return displayName();`, `myFunc` will return `undefined` and the value of the variable `myFunc` assigned to `undefined` because call to `displayName` actually return `undefined` or absolutely nothing(it just make a call to `alert` and then ends). So when try to call `myFunc` which is `undefined` it will give you a type error.

But when you `return displayName;`, the function `makeFunc` return a function and `myFunc` will assign to a proper function and just run fine.

Answer (score 0):

"The second one makes the code work how I want it to work? is this how youre supposed to return functions?"
Well yes and yes.

That pattern that you're applying is called function factory, that is a function that returns another function, that you later call.

Comment: But the first code is the reason the alert in the inner function is ran thats why i am confused because you call a function like this => nameOfFunction() ;

Comment: when you do `return displayName()` it's translated to `return alert('hello')`  so the alert it's executed and at the end the return value of `alert('hello')` it's returned. And that value is void

Answer (score 0):

I would say when you do `return displayName();` you are returning the result of the function and then when you do `myFunc();` you are treating that result as a function. In the current scenario, it is a undefined but it could also be a string or int. Contrary, when you do `return displayName` you are returning a function definition that can be invoked by doing `myFunc()`.